# Dom4J: How to replace an XML Element by its text value

Tags: java, dom4j

I am using dom4j to parse xml like this:

```
<node>
    somestring<br/>some <a href="stackoverflow.com">another string</a> 
</node>
```

And I want to change this to another xml like this:

```
<node>
    somestring<br/>some another string
</node>
```

Is that possible with dom4j?

I think the trick is to parse the node inside text.

Comment: There is no "trick" or additional parsing needed. `<node>` has mixed content, i.e. text followed by an empty `<br>` element followed by more text (the space) and an `<a>` element.  You should see DOM nodes for all these objects.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yeah I can get all the text by element.getText().But how to replace the node in order? Consider replace the <br> elment with string "\n" and the string become "somestring \n some another string".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want to do by running through your node Element content and replacing the "a" tag by its text value.

So assuming you have the node into an `Element` object

```
String originalXml = "<node>somestring<br/>some <a href=\"stackoverflow.com\">another string</a></node>";
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(originalXml);
Element nodeElement = document.getRootElement();
```

You can do it this way, see inline comments:

```
// once you have your node, as an Element object, get its content
List<Object> content = nodeElement.content();

// go through the content list and replace any "a" tag by its text value
List<Object> newContent = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object o : content) {
  Object newContentObject = o; // keep the same value by default
  if(o instanceof DefaultElement) {
    DefaultElement elem = (DefaultElement)o;
    String tagName = elem.getQName().getName();
    if("a".equals(tagName)) // this is an "a" tag, replace it by a text element
      newContentObject = new DefaultText(elem.getText());
  }
  newContent.add(newContentObject);
}

// Set the new content to your element
nodeElement.setContent(newContent);

System.out.print(nodeElement.asXML());
```

This outputs:

```
<node>somestring<br/>some another string</node>
```